# problema en hacer migrate en windows 10 heroku django

Tags: django, heroku

estoy intentando hacer heroku run python manage.py migrate desde git y me sale el siguiente error :

`

```
heroku run python manage.py migrate
Running python manage.py migrate on `enter code here`tornilub... starting, run.3211 (Free)
Running python manage.py migrate on tornilub... connecting, run.3211 (Free)Running python manage.py migrate on tornilub... up, run.3211 (Free)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/app/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 414, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 460, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 98, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 91, in handle
    self.check(databases=[database])
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 487, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 480, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 49, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 696, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 49, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 689, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/app/irsmain/urls.py", line 18, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "/app/irsmain/views.py", line 2, in <module>
    from tienda.views import Productos
  File "/app/tienda/views.py", line 3, in <module>
    from subprocess import IDLE_PRIORITY_CLASS
ImportError: cannot import name 'IDLE_PRIORITY_CLASS' from 'subprocess' (/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py)
```

`

me gustaria saber que esta pasando, tambien sale este error en el navegador al hacer heroku open

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el deploy tengo entendido que salio perfecto, tengan en cuenta que estoy haciendo el deploy desde Windows 10, algunas personas me han dicho que es porque mi sistema operativo no es Linux, pero viendo los tutoriales veo que usan Windows, tengan en cuenta que es mi primer deploy,estoy aprendiendo en todo esto, gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

Se me habia colado un import de IDLE_PRIORITY_CLASS en una de las views, vsc lo puso solo, esta solucionado

Comment: Súper! Estaría lindo si muestras qué viste y en qué archivo, con eso otros sabrán dónde buscar en este caso. De hecho, puedes marcar tu respuesta como aceptada en unas horas

Comment: en una de mis vistas tenia esto from subprocess import IDLE_PRIORITY_CLASS, vsc lo agrego solo, solo lo tuve que borrar y soluciono el problema